# how to pass view method param to user passes test in django?

Tags: django

i have a view method such as

```
@login_required(login_url='/users/login')
def my_submission(request,submission_id):

    submission = Submission.objects.get(pk=submission_id)

    return render(request, "assignments/mysubmission.html", {
            "submission": submission
        })
```

I was wondering if there is a way to pass submission_id which is the second param to user passes test decorator so that i can do something like

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.id == Submission.objects.get(pk=submission_id).user.id, login_url='/')
```

thanks for the guide in advance.

Comment: Its very easy with CBV actually with the userpassestest mixin. You can access the entire view object and get request params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just write it as a check in the view:

```py
@login_required(login_url='/users/login')
def my_submission(request,submission_id):

    submission = Submission.objects.get(pk=submission_id)
    if submission.user_id != request.user.pk:
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request, "assignments/mysubmission.html", {
            "submission": submission
        })
```

#### Update

If you use this many times, consider implementing it is a class-based view, so you could inherit and utilize some extra features:

```py
class UserIsOwnerMixin(AccessMixin):
    """Verify that the user the owner of related object."""
    owner_id_field = 'user_id'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated or getattr(self.get_object(), self.owner_field) != request.user.pk:
            return self.handle_no_permission()

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class SubmissionView(UserIsOwnerMixin, DetailView):
    template = "assignments/mysubmission.html"
    model = Submission
    context_object_name = "submission"
    login_url = '/users/login'
```

Comment: thanks but i was searching for a flexible more succinct way. that check is common and will be used in many view methods in other words it will do the work of acl but i dont want to use acl libraries.

Comment: i see, so the mixin can be reused in multiple view methods?

Comment: Exactly, you can also use the `owner_id_field` to specify the name of the Foreign Key field to use as owner field.

Comment: thanks for the help. ill follow this approach.

Comment: i went ahead and used the first approach non class based view for the sake of readability. thanks.